# PIL im.getdata file format

Tags: python, format, python-imaging-library

I'm new for Python, so sorry for stupid question. When I call for list(im.getdata()) the result looks like a list with triple-tuple inside. Simple list commands such as sum() doesn't want to work, claiming:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Poos\Desktop\G\SS.py", line 8, in <module>
    y = sum(x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

What should I do to operate with this data as with a "normal" list? Thanks and sorry for English inaccuracies

Comment: Please post your code that cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

The list returned is the RGB value for each pixel, so each element *should* be a tuple with three elements. I don't know what you want to accomplish by summing the elements. If you want to determine the 'total red component', you can use list comprehension:

```
red = sum([x[0] for x in list(im.getdata())])
```

Maybe we can help you better if you better describe what you want to achieve.

**Equivalence**

Edit after first comment: if you want to check if two images are *equal*, then you can compare the data, or the images directly.

```
>>> a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
>>> b = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
>>> a == b
True

>>>> from PIL import Image
>>> a = Image.new("RGB", (250,250), "red")
>>> b = Image.new("RGB", (250,250), "red")
>>> a == b
True
>>> b.putpixel((100,100), (100,100,100))
>>> a == b
False
```

If you don't want to check for another kind of equivalence, you must specify more in detail what you mean with equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to create a kind of code that will quickly test two images for equivalence. I suppose, that the way of summing the image pixels data and comparison of these two values will be ok. But if there is a easier way, I will be grateful if you will enlighten me